# Unable to listen to background notifications with $cordovaPushV5

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using [$cordovaPushV5](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotificationsV5/) plugin to manage push notifications in my iconic-based app:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', (event, notification) => {
  pusherService.parseNotification(notification);
});
```

The code above works as expected ONLY when I am inside the app. But it doesn't do anything when notification is received in the background (after I close or exit the app with the home button).

Although, I do receive notifications in the notification area of my devices (iPhone and Samsung Galaxy).

Is there a way to make my app respond to notifications when it isn't open? I'll appreciate any form of input from you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ionic push notification you can handle it in following way

```js
   $rootScope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(event, data) {
     $localStorage.pushNotification = data;
     var msg = data.message;
     /*When push notification open if application is in sleep state following code is given true*/
     var isAppSleep = msg.app.asleep;
     /*When push notification open if application is in closed state following code is given true*/
     var isAppClosed = msg.app.closed;

   });
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this, but my problem is with capturing bg notifications, not in handling them, sorry if I confused you in my question title (changed). Plus, I wanna achieve this with $cordovaPushV5.